# suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle is not working for Symfony2 in dev environment

Tags: ios, iphone, symfony, mobile, bundle

I have added [MobileDetectBundle](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle) working with prod environment but not with dev.

Code in config.yml is below:


    `mobile_detect:
        redirect:
            mobile:
                is_enabled: true            # default false
                host: http://m.site.com     # with scheme (http|https), default null, url validate
                status_code: 301            # default 302
                action: redirect            # redirect, no_redirect, redirect_without_path
            tablet:
                is_enabled: false            # default false
            detect_tablet_as_mobile: false   # default false
        switch_device_view:
            save_referer_path: false        # default trueenter code here`

When load prod environment url on iPhone simulator I get redirected to the set host. But for dev url redirection does not happen. Both prod and dev ymls have the same content.

Am I missing anything?

Appreciate for any helps.

Comment: Verify that cookie has not been set before. If you have prod and dev running on same domain it can be a reason.